# What is the parity of a $W^{-}$ boson?

Tags: particle-physics, parity, weak-interaction, electroweak

What is the parity eigenvalue of the $W^{\pm}$ boson, or is it even an eigenstate? I have not found any source that discusses this. I have seen some lists of particles with their parity eigenvalues, but the $W^{\pm}$ and $Z^{0}$ bosons are always left out.

Comment: Parity is broken in the Electroweak interactions. Only CP is a (n approximate) good symmetry. But $W^{\pm}$ are not eigenstates being charged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here is the particle table](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/tables/rpp2013-sum-gauge-higgs-bosons.pdf) for exchange bosons. You will see that the massive intermediate bosons are not assigned a parity.

Parity is an operator. To have a definite value the state must be an eigenvalue of this operator. In the case of the massive weak interaction mediating bosons no such eigenvalue exists  because in the standard model [they carry  both an axial vector and a vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Violation_of_symmetry)  component, so the operator cannot be diagonal. This is what induces  parity violation in weak interactions. A better formulation is that the observation of parity violating weak interactions forced the model to have massive vector and axial vector exchange bosons. Another source that might help is [this one](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/teach/module_home/px435/weak.pdf).

Comment: i agree with this answer, but in your second link, top of p3, parity $P_{W^+}=P_{W^-}=-1$. huh? is the link, mark thompson's cambridge lecture notes, wrong?

Comment: @innisfree thanks for catching it. I believe it is wrong for massive (broken symmetry) bosons, but I will do further checks. It could just be a choice of the standard model. I will edit a new link to vector axial vector.

Comment: I understand that the fermionic currents that couples to the W are V-A (vector - axial vector) currents, but does this imply that W itself is V-A?

Comment: It is not in an eigen state of parity and that is why it is not given a parity in the data book.

Comment: @innisfree This goes towards parity symmetry restored at higher energies http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6486

Comment: the original link referred to in my previous comment is http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_9_2011.pdf